# Lost passport and visa, tried to reapply, got rejected twice. What are my next steps?

Tags: visas, canada

I got student visa from February 2018 to july 2020. I came Canada in Winnipeg at ICM college  but I can't satisfy towards subject and I can't manage my fees of degree that's why I take diploma in Red River college in Winnipeg.

During study I leave for 7 days from college and I came in India.  Here, I lost my passport which has a valid visa and study permit and so many important documents. That's why i can't came or enter in  Canada with visa. Again I apply new passport and apply student visa I faced refusal than I contact with consultant in India and he apply my visitor visa because I want to paste my same visa on new passport but unfortunately I again faced refusal.

Please help me to get visa and can be paste same visa on new passport I send you my both refusal letter.

When I came Canada in 2018 at Vancouver border I received wrong or mistake study permit in study permit they mentioned wrong sex like Male I'm female that's why they don't gave me part time work hours.. Then I contact with lawyer in Winnipeg he provided me New study permit with correction. Before my passport has a single but now when we make new passport in show married in  my caips notes also. I have scan documents which have old passport with stamp and also study permit. Can I travel with scan documents.

Comment: What do you mean your lawyer provided you with a new study permit?

Comment: Did you use an agent to get your original study visa? The mistake about your gender sounds strange. And what does being male or female have to do with whether you get part time work hours? Are you single or married?

Comment: That is a big time mess. No one here can be of any help at this point. You really need a really good lawyer.

Comment: @JonathonReez (title editor) Tried to reapply for what/which? Passports and visas are separate applications.

Comment: @Traveller I was in Canada on a study permit and had trouble with my work authorization. There are steps to being able to start a job besides getting a study permit at the border. Perhaps somewhere along the way someone noticed the gender discrepancy and refused to go farther. I would believe it.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

OK, you've done pretty much everything wrong so far.

1. When you changed your course of study you should have told immigration. You wouldn't have needed a new study permit.
2. When you lost your study permit and visitor visa you should have applied for a copy, not applied for a new visa.
3. It is not surprising that you were refused another study permit since you already had one. If you hadn't told Canadian immigration that you had changed colleges, and you applied in the name of the new one, then it is even less surprising. They won't grant you a permit to study at a college if they think you are already studying at a different one.
4. You did not need a lawyer to fix the mistakes in the visa and permit (like a wrong gender). You should simply have contacted immigration as soon as you got them. It is important that you do this, because having the wrong gender means the document looks like it might be fake.
5. Your gender, whether correct on your study permit or not, would not have affected whether you were given part time work hours. Discriminating on the basis of gender would be illegal in Canada.
6. There are serious restrictions on what work you can do while in Canada on a study permit. That is more likely to have affected your ability to work. Or they may suspect your study permit is fake, because of the error in the gender.
7. You should get mistakes in your passport corrected before you travel, by telling the Indian authorities.
8. No, you cannot travel with scans of your visa or permit. You can theoretically still apply for a copy of your existing permits and visa, which should get you into Canada.

However, as Hanky Panky says, you and your lawyer have made a big mess of this by doing the wrong thing many times. It is likely that Canadian Immigration think there is something underhand happening.

I would ask for copies of your current visa and permit. And call your college and ask for advice. Most Canadian colleges have departments specifically set up to help International students, and may have someone who speaks your native language. If that does not work then either get a completely different lawyer (one with actual experience of Canadian visas) or abandon your studies in Canada.

Comment: Would it be possible to get help from the university? I have never been to Canada but where I live in such a situation the school would be happy to help. (Although they have no in-house council any native would have an easier time figuring out the Canadian process – from the OP’s English I’m guessing there may have been a communication problem.)

Comment: Good point. Edited to say that.

Comment: Also if you're going to engage the services of a lawyer, get one that makes your situation better, not worse. I used an immigration lawyer when my wife was getting her green card and it made things run super smooth. We checked him out and he had good references. Should be plenty of free resources to help with this, but if you're going to pay, get your money's worth!

Comment: @corsiKa - that is to say a Canadian lawyer, presumably.

Comment: @simonatrcl Actually the lawyer was from Winnepeg, according to OP.

Comment: re: #5, (assuming legal on-campus or degree related co-op job) it is entirely reasonable for an employer to require *accurate* proof of the right to work in Canada if it looks like you might be using your friend's document who happens to have the same name or something like that!  (or possibly Service Canada refused to issue a temporary SIN because an inaccurate document was provided to them.)

Comment: See also: https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/manitoba/private-manitoba-college-misleading-students-some-say-1.1234870